# Facebook conversion pixel with values

Tags: magento-1.9

I can only find some suggestions for the 'old' pixel to get the correct values for amount and currency. How do I magento-fy this new version?

```
<!-- Facebook Conversion Code -->
<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
}
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'ID', {'value':'0.01','currency':'EUR'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=ID&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=EUR&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

And should I really place it in head, not succes.phtml?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem with putting this script in success.phtml to track conversion data for facebook.

If you want to get the order value use something like

```
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order');
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$_totalData =$order->getData();
$_conversion_value = number_format($_totalData['grand_total'],2);
```

and then in the fb script

```
window._fbq.push(['track', 'ID', {'value':'<?php echo $_conversion_value ?>','currency':'EUR'}]);

<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=ID&amp;cd[value]=<?php echo $_conversion_value ?>&amp;cd[currency]=EUR&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

Comment: Thanks. Shouldn't it be added in the `<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=ID&amp;cd[value]=0.01&amp;cd[currency]=EUR&amp;noscript=1" /></noscript>` also?

Comment: yes you should add the value there too, if required you could extract the currency code from Magento as well if your shop has multiple currencies